# Sinch message client listeners not called

Tags: android, sinch

I'm trying to use Sinch to add messaging functionality to my Android app,
but when I send a message, no one of the `MessageClientListener` functions is called (I checked this with simple log in every function of the listener). The result is the same if I run the `sinch-rtc-sample-messaging` application, which is included in the Sinch's android sdk (downloaded [here](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/)).

I import the sample app to Android Studio and the only things I changed are the `APP-KEY` and `APP-SECRET`. I am wondering if this issue is something related to the Sinch's jni libraries and the ART runtime? Or is it related to Android Lollipop?

I searched for similar problems all day long and no useful help,
the logcat provided messages is as below:

```
04-12 18:44:51.695  11971-11971/com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-12 18:44:51.695  11971-11971/com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-12 18:44:51.695  11971-11971/com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-12 18:44:51.695  11971-11971/com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging I/InputMethodManager﹕ [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging, inputType=0x20001, imeOptions=0x44000006, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=null, mServedView=android.widget.EditText{3430a3c5 VFED..CL .F...... 30,12-810,143 #7f07000a app:id/txtTextBody}, mServedInputConnectionWrapper=android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper@12b30220
```

This happens whenever I click `send` button in the example application.

Environment:

- Android Studio 1.1.0
- HTC new one (m7), Android version 5.0.2

I'm new to posting questions on StackOverflow, if any other information should I provide for solving problem please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your internet connectivity? If the device is offline the message might have been queued up for delivery later, in which case it wont trigger any of the callbacks until the device is online again

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Any solution for this?